# php -> JSON -> iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I have an iPhone app which sends a request to a url posting a variable called submit:

```
+(NSMutableArray*)getQuestions:(NSString*)section from: (NSString*) url{
    NSMutableArray *questions = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    //connect to database given by url
    //NSError        *error = nil;
    //NSURLResponse  *response = nil;
    NSMutableString* myRequestString = [[NSMutableString string]initWithFormat:@"section=%@", section];
    NSData *myRequestData = [NSData dataWithBytes: [myRequestString UTF8String] length: [myRequestString length]];
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL: [NSURL URLWithString: url]]; 
    [request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"content-type"];
    [request setHTTPMethod: @"POST"];
    //post section 
    [request setHTTPBody: myRequestData];

    //store them in the array;
    return [questions autorelease];
}
```

My php file:

```
<?php

//connect to database
function connect() {
  $dbh = mysql_connect ("localhost", "abc1", "12345") or die ('I cannot connect to the database because: ' . mysql_error());
  mysql_select_db("PDS", $dbh); 
  return $dbh;
}

//store posted data
if(isset($_POST['section'])){
  $dbh = connect();
  $section = $_POST['section'];
  $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM QUESTIONS WHERE sectionId = $section;") or die("Error: " . mysql_error());;

  $rows = array();
  while($r = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
    $rows[] = $r;
  }
  echo '{"questions":'.json_encode($rows).'}';
  mysql_close();
}
?>
```

I have built a model class (Question) in objective c which has the exact properties that each row element has in the rows associative array.

My questions are:

1) How can I read the echo'd JSON array elements and their relative attributes in objective C?

2) How can I create an array of Question objects and map each one to an element in the rows array?

3) What do I have to write in my method "+(NSMutableArray*)getQuestions:(NSString*)section from: (NSString*) url" to capture the reply from the php (the echo)?

EDIT:

Here is the output of the php:

http://dev.speechlink.co.uk/David/get_questionstest.php

UPDATE

Changed method to use ASIHTTPRequest - Cannot deserialise JSON string:

```
//method to 
+(NSDictionary*)getQuestions:(NSString*)sectionId from: (NSString*) url{
    NSDictionary *questions;
    NSURL *link = [NSURL URLWithString:url];
    ASIFormDataRequest *request = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:link];
    [request setPostValue:sectionId forKey:@"section"];
    NSError *error = [request error];
    [request startAsynchronous];

    if (!error) {       
        //NSString *response = [request responseString];
        //store them in the dictionary
        NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];
        NSString *json = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        questions = [json objectFromJSONString];
        NSLog(@"Data: %@", questions); //outputs Data: (null)
        [json release];
        [request release];      
    }else{
        //UIAlertView to warn users there was an error
    }               

    return questions;   
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, lets go through this one step at a time.

You can create a `NSDictionary` from JSON quite easily by using one of several different JSON parsing libraries.  I really enjoy using [JSONKit](https://github.com/johnezang/JSONKit).  Once you've imported `JSONKit`, into your project, you can do something like this:

```
NSString *url = @"http://dev.speechlink.co.uk/David/get_questionstest.php";
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];
NSString *json = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSDictionary *questions = [json objectFromJSONString];
[json release];
```

Now you have an array filled with the questions in your example.  Now you can loop through this array and fill your data with the data in the array.  Now lets be practical.  It would be easier if you just had to manage one object instead of four for each question, wouldn't it?  Lets make a class that contains one question each instance.

---

Interface:

```
@interface Question : NSObject {
    NSString *questionId;
    NSString *question;
    NSString *questionNumber;
    NSString *sectionId;
}
@property(copy)NSString *questionID; 
@property(copy)NSString *question; 
@property(copy)NSString *questionNumber; 
@property(copy)NSString *sectionId; 

@end
```

And implementation:

```
@implementation Question
@synthesize questionId, question, questionNumber, sectionID;

@end
```

---

Now that's just a basic example.  Nothing fancy.  Now you can loop through the array you had before and create "question" objects that contain each question's data.  For my purposes, suppose you have a `NSMutableArray` named `questionsArray` that contain the questions you want to use.  We'll loop through the dictionary and add the questions from the dictionary into the `questionsArray` array.

```
for (NSDictionary *q in questions) {
    /* Create our Question object and populate it */
    Question *question = [[Question alloc]init];
    question.questionId = [q objectForKey:@"questionId"];
    question.question = [q objectForKey:@"question"];
    question.questionNumber = [q objectForKey:@"questionNumber"];
    question.sectionId = [q objectForKey:@"sectionId"];

    /* Add it to our question (mutable) array */
    [questionsArray addObject:question];
    [question release];
}
```

Tada!  Now you have an array filled with `Question` objects.  Any time you want to look at a property on any of the question objects, you can just simply access that property.  For example, to grab the first question's number, you can just do this:

```
NSString *q1Number = [questionsArray objectAtIndex:0].questionNumber;
```

---

Please note this is all untested, as I don't have my compiler with me.  It should get you started, though. =)

---

**Edit:** You were doing your request completely wrong.  Try this:

```
+(NSDictionary*)getQuestions:(NSString*)sectionId from: (NSString*) url{
    NSDictionary *questions = nil;
    NSURL *link = [NSURL URLWithString:url];
    ASIFormDataRequest *request = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:link];
    [request setPostValue:sectionId forKey:@"section"];
    NSError *error = [request error];
    [request startSynchronous];

    if (!error) { 
        NSData *response = [request responseData];
        NSString *json = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:response encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        questions = [json objectFromJSONString];
        [json release];
    } else{
        //UIAlertView to warn users there was an error
    }               
    [request release];
     return questions;
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply. When doing an NSLog on the questions I get null, why might this be?

Comment: Then you're not getting your data properly.  Try logging `questions` (created from this line: `NSDictionary *questions = [json objectFromJSONString];`).  See if that contains data.

Comment: Hi that too returns null. I;m not sure where I;m getting the data incorrectly. when viewing the link in a browser to the HTML (removing all issets for posted data) the JSON string is displayed properly..

Comment: Updated my post to show you new method and where I'm logging questions

Comment: When you use `startAsynchronous`, that means the data might not be availible in calls directly after that.  If you want it to wait, use `startSynchronous`. The data should exist then.

Comment: Using startSynchronous causes my app to crash immediately. Also, I want the user to be able to use the app while the data is submitting...Is there no way to wait until data has finished loading

Comment: Yeah you can, but you have to use `startAsynchronous` with a callback method.  Look at the `ASIHTTPRequest` documentation.  It's really easy to follow.

Comment: Ive looked but im finding it hard to follow. I cannot get requestFailed callback to trigger...

Comment: That's because the request is probably working.  I think something you're doing with the data is causing it to crash.  Can't you check your console output and see what it's logging after the crash?  Does it display a backtrace?

Comment: My app doesn;t crash in its existing state, it just doesnt call the delegate method..nothing gets logged except my Data: (null)\

Comment: [Session started at 2011-07-14 11:52:03 +0100.]
2011-07-14 11:52:09.296 dbQuestionGetter[16703:207] Data: (null)

Comment: You're doing it completely wrong.  Here, I'll put it in my debugger and fix it for you.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at Stig Brautaset's excellent JSON parser at [GitHub](https://github.com/stig/json-framework/).

And there are even a couple of sample projects included.

From your PHP, one would expect the parser to produce and array of NSDictionary objects. I'm not sure what you mean by question 2, but you can then iterate through the array and create custom "Question" objects with the NSDictionary values.

Hope this helps.

Didn't see that you added a third question. This is answered in the "TweetStream" example above. I would suggest that you use the NSURLConnectionDelegate methods as described by [Apple](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/Tasks/UsingNSURLConnection.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001836-BAJEAIEE).